# Native Exchange Email app does not synchronize folders properly

Tags: sync, email, exchange, motorola-milestone

Recently I created/removed some folders on Outlook desktop app.

When I synchronized my corporate account by manually refreshing under the folders screen, it didn't bring the new folders, nor removed the removed ones.

Is this a known bug?

I have a Motorola Milestone, and I remember in the past, at least the folder addition worked.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I have not seen this behavior on my Droid, although it does seem to take a bit of time to get fully synchronized.

Comment: As a workaround, I deleted the account and registered it again, and it worked, but I'm not sure if this can be considered a "solution".

Comment: I think you should post that as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.  The Mail app is very buggy and basic and until it is improved I suspect there is no other solution.

Comment: @Matthew agree, although I've started to try Touchdown as an alternative, I think it's fine for this specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting my account and registering it again, and it worked, but this is a workaround.

As pointed out by other people, the native Mail app is buggy, so I started evaluating Touchdown.

Answer (score 1):

I know you were going for the "onboard" solution for Exchange e-mail, but at my workplace a bunch of folks use Touchdown:

http://www.appbrain.com/app/exchange-by-touchdown-key/com.nitrodesk.touchdownpro

Only problem is that is is $19.99. It works well with ActiveSync policies and doesn't force you to encrypt your whole device if your SysAdmin has required as such.

Comment: another problem with TouchDown is battery drain. I finally had to uninstall it because it was draining my battery several times faster than the stock email app.