# How can I get the stock mail application in Android to sync all my Exchange/Outlook contact folders?

Tags: contacts, exchange, outlook

Device: Samsung Galaxy (T959)
OS: Android 2.1 (stock from T-Mobile USA)
Exchange Server 2007 Enterprise

**How can I get the stock mail application in Android to sync all my Exchange/Outlook contact folders?**

I have several contact folders off my "Mailbox" root. Here is the directory structure:

Mailbox - [my name]
..Contacts **(<< correctly sync'ing to phone)**
..Contacts - Family **(<< not sync'ing to phone)**
..Contacts - PRC **(<< not sync'ing to phone)**
..Contacts - Vendors **(<< not sync'ing to phone)**
..Inbox

I know that originally the iPhone didn't sync all the contact folders but it does now. Any hints on how to get Android 2.1 to do it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/native-exchange-email-app-does-not-synchronize-folders-properly

Answer (score 1):

Touchdown is your only option to fix this. An admin at my company got his Motorola Droid 2 and had the same problem. We tried everything we could find online in an attempt to sync all his contacts. Eventually we came across touchdown, paid the 19.99 and it worked fine. With the exception of notes it cleared up all the short comings of the stock Android Exchange sync.

Side Note: I don't personally use Touchdown nor am I affiliated with them in any way.

Comment: EDIT: it was a Droid 2