# How to see additional email folders from corporate account email?

Tags: cyanogenmod, email, windows, outlook

I have access to my corporate email that is viewed using Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 on Windows 7.  In my Outlook, I have filters that move some emails into folders, however, on my Android email account view of my corporate email, I only see the emails in my 'Inbox' folder.

Is there a way to get some or all of my other folders visible on my Android running Cyongenmod 7?

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/native-exchange-email-app-does-not-synchronize-folders-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders are already there, by default your Inbox is shown, while inside your Inbox, choose Menu => Folders and you will see a list of all your corporate folders.  Pick one to switch to viewing it.